# MATLAB auto zoom to specific point when figure is created

Tags: matlab, plot, zooming, matlab-figure, figure

I have written some code that will follow the black edge shown in the attached image. each time the next point is picked the figure is redrawn to show the update. this is done so i can demonstrate the code in an animated way.

[image]

i want to automatically zoom in on a specific point (the centre cyan point surrounded by red squares). the hope is that the auto zoomed area will follow the point as it traces the black edge.

The following code is written as a function and i call it on my main script every time the next edge pixel is detected.

I have tried setting the range of the axis to be a range surrounding the POI however i couldn't get it working.

```
function draw_point2(BinaryImage, P, P_r, P_c)
%P is a 1x2 array for the position of the current black pixel.
%P_r is nx1 list of all the row values for the detected pixels.
%P_c is nx1 list of all the column values for the detected pixels.


    cla
    r = P(1,1);
    c = P(1,2);
    figure (100)
    imshow(BinaryImage) , title('Binary image')
    hold on;
    plot(P_c, P_r, 'c.', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on
    %Current Black Pixel
    plot(c, r, 'c.', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on;

    % Possible Black Pixel - Next
    plot(c, r+1, 'rs', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on
    plot(c, r-1, 'rs', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on
    plot(c-1, r, 'rs', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on
    plot(c+1, r, 'rs', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on
    plot(c-1, r+1, 'rs', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on
    plot(c-1, r-1, 'rs', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on
    plot(c+1, r+1, 'rs', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on
    plot(c+1, r-1, 'rs', 'LineWidth', 2); hold on
    axis equal
    truesize;
end
```

Thanks

---

***EDIT1***

The following image shows the desired output next to the current one. (it shows how i would like the figure to look when it is drawn. It shows the zoom (and centre) the POI. in an ideal case the POI would also always be centred in the figure
[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you actually expect the output to look like? It's hard to tell from your description.

Comment: i have edited the question to try and what what the desired output should look like.

Comment: @bilaly any problem with my answer? can I help you somehow else? Please tell me so I can add more if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `axis`.

You can define the limits by using `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])`. In your case `xmin` would be something like `c-20` and `xmax=c+20`.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply.. unfortunately placing this code near where the plots are drawn works if i am stepping through the code however when left to run on it's own and the code loops to the find the next next point the figure isn't updated.

Comment: @bilaly that means that somewhere, something is overwriting the instruction. Maybe `truesize`? You need to go step by step and see what instruction is actually "unzooming" your image.

Comment: i have it working just fine when i step through the code. The zoom works when i step through the code. the updated image is shown with the zoom. when i run the code normally the image is not updated. i found that by placing a `pause(0.1)` after the plots are all drawn makes it work as intended. i think the code was just running too fast the updated image and zoom didn't have enough time to be generated before the next one was drawn.

Comment: @bilaly instead o fpause, try `drawnow`